# How to identify which disk failed on RAID 10?

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, drive-failure

RAID 10 set up from 16 SATA (4TB) disks. How to identify from pictures which disk is failed?

Here is my screenshots:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

The output of lcpci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 DMI2 (rev 04)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1a (rev 04)
00:01.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1b (rev 04)
00:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2a (rev 04)
00:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3a (rev 04)
00:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 0 (rev 04)
00:04.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 1 (rev 04)
00:04.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 2 (rev 04)
00:04.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 3 (rev 04)
00:04.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 4 (rev 04)
00:04.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 5 (rev 04)
00:04.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 6 (rev 04)
00:04.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 7 (rev 04)
00:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 VTd/Memory Map/Misc (rev 04)
00:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IIO RAS (rev 04)
00:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IOAPIC (rev 04)
00:11.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset PCI Express Virtual Root Port (rev 06)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset MEI Controller #1 (rev 05)
00:16.1 Communication controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset MEI Controller #2 (rev 05)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b6)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset LPC Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset 6-Port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset SMBus Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation C600/X79 series chipset Thermal Management Controller (rev 06)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
03:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
05:00.0 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)
06:00.0 Serial Attached SCSI controller: Intel Corporation C602 chipset 4-Port SATA Storage Control Unit (rev 06)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
07:00.1 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
07:00.2 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
07:00.3 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I350 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 01)
09:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)
7f:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
7f:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 04)
7f:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 0 (rev 04)
7f:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 1 (rev 04)
7f:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 2 (rev 04)
7f:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 3 (rev 04)
7f:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
7f:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
7f:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
7f:0e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
7f:0e.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
7f:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address/Thermal Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 RAS Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
7f:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 0 (rev 04)
7f:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 1 (rev 04)
7f:10.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 0 (rev 04)
7f:10.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 1 (rev 04)
7f:10.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 2 (rev 04)
7f:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 3 (rev 04)
7f:10.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 2 (rev 04)
7f:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 3 (rev 04)
7f:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
7f:13.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
7f:13.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Registers (rev 04)
7f:13.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Performance Ring Monitoring (rev 04)
7f:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 System Address Decoder (rev 04)
7f:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
7f:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
80:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 1a (rev 04)
80:02.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 2a (rev 04)
80:03.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 PCI Express Root Port 3a (rev 04)
80:04.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 0 (rev 04)
80:04.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 1 (rev 04)
80:04.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 2 (rev 04)
80:04.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 3 (rev 04)
80:04.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 4 (rev 04)
80:04.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 5 (rev 04)
80:04.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 6 (rev 04)
80:04.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Crystal Beach DMA Channel 7 (rev 04)
80:05.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 VTd/Memory Map/Misc (rev 04)
80:05.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IIO RAS (rev 04)
80:05.4 PIC: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 IOAPIC (rev 04)
ff:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 0 (rev 04)
ff:09.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Link 1 (rev 04)
ff:0a.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 0 (rev 04)
ff:0a.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 1 (rev 04)
ff:0a.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 2 (rev 04)
ff:0a.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Power Control Unit 3 (rev 04)
ff:0b.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
ff:0b.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 UBOX Registers (rev 04)
ff:0c.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0c.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0d.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0d.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Unicast Registers (rev 04)
ff:0e.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
ff:0e.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Home Agent 0 (rev 04)
ff:0f.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Target Address/Thermal Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 RAS Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:0f.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 0 Channel Target Address Decoder Registers (rev 04)
ff:10.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 0 (rev 04)
ff:10.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 1 (rev 04)
ff:10.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 0 (rev 04)
ff:10.3 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 1 (rev 04)
ff:10.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 2 (rev 04)
ff:10.5 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 Thermal Control 3 (rev 04)
ff:10.6 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 2 (rev 04)
ff:10.7 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Integrated Memory Controller 1 Channel 0-3 ERROR Registers 3 (rev 04)
ff:13.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
ff:13.1 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 R2PCIe (rev 04)
ff:13.4 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Registers (rev 04)
ff:13.5 Performance counters: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 QPI Ring Performance Ring Monitoring (rev 04)
ff:16.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 System Address Decoder (rev 04)
ff:16.1 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
ff:16.2 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E7 v2/Xeon E5 v2/Core i7 Broadcast Registers (rev 04)
```

Comment: What make and model of controller?

Comment: The led light on the server front panel?

Comment: @Chopper3, SMS (SuperMicro) Storage. I've added the picture of server.

Comment: @AntonelloCordella , Yes, there are led lights on server front panel ,but there is no alarm led lights.

Answer (score 0):

### In general...

If your disc location path `0:2:0:0:` and `sda` refers to the same & single physical drive, then that's it.

If the hardware RAID is hidden from the operating system and `0:2:0:0:` / `sda` therefore refers to the RAID itself (as it probably in this case does), there's no way to tell only from these screenshots. Then, you should check your RAID controller's manual on how this information can be obtained.

---

### Details: How do we know even if the user doesn't...

If you can't find the [manual](https://www.supermicro.nl/support/manuals/), you could contact your reseller for [Supermicro Service and Support](https://www.supermicro.nl/support/index.cfm):

> In order to maximize support resources, Supermicro works through
>   reseller channels to resolve technical support issues and provide RMA
>   services. All end users requiring technical support or RMA services
>   are encouraged to contact their vendor directly. Supermicro resellers
>   have complete access to our technical support and RMA teams; thus they
>   are able to obtain fast and efficient responses to end user technical
>   support issues and RMA services.

It seems Supermicro uses (and has Installation Guides for) RAID controllers from:

- Intel, with [Intel PCH RAID Config](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/Intel_PCH_RAID_Config.pdf), [HostRAID](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/HostRAID_ICH7R_ICH9R_ICH10R.pdf) or [ESB2 SATA](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/RAID_SATA_ESB2.pdf): press Ctrl + I when asked on boot.
- LSI, with [MegaRAID](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/LSI%20MegaRAID_Configuration_for_the_LSI_1068_Controller.pdf), Ctrl + M or [Ctrl + H](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/LSI_2108_2208_SAS_MegaRAID_Configuration_Utility.pdf), [HostRAID](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/LSI_HostRAID_2308.pdf) Ctrl + C during initialization screen.

Your [SS6037R-E1R16N](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/superserver/3U/MNL-1527.pdf) says it has [AOC-USAS2LP-H8iR
Add-on Card](https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/AOC-USAS2LP-H8iR.pdf) having probably [MegaRAID](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/LSI_2108_2208_SAS_MegaRAID_Configuration_Utility.pdf), confirmed by `lspci` line:

```
05:00 RAID bus controller: LSI Logic / Symbios Logic MegaRAID SAS 2108 [Liberator] (rev 05)
```

> Press CTRL and H to enter the LSI MegaRAID Configuration Utility
>   after the controller is initialized.

And there:

> 2-6 Scan Devices
>
> From the configuration utility main screen, use the
>   mouse or the *Tab* key to select Scan Devices. This feature checks the
>   physical and virtual drives for any changes in drive status. Any
>   changes in drive status are displayed in the drive descriptions.

**Please learn how to find and [read manuals](http://www.wikihow.com/Use-a-Maintenance-Manual).**

Comment: Could you clarify your answer? How to check the RAID controller?

Comment: Could you clarify your question? SuperMicro has several product families from small to huge and even within one product line there could be RAID controllers from LSI, Marvell, Intel... The answer depends on the controller and the controller depends on the product.

Comment: An `lspci` output would help here.

Comment: Supermicro SSG-6037R-E1R16N/X9DRi-LN4+/X9DR3-LN4+. 
Here is the link to this server page : https://www.supermicro.com/products/system/3U/6037/SSG-6037R-E1R16N.cfm

Comment: @SmallLoanOf1M, the question is updated and added the output of lspci.

Comment: This seems to be the best answer here so far.  If you need help physically identifying the drive (once you know which drive it is) there was a similar Q/A which tells how to make the HDD LED blink here: http://serverfault.com/a/799793

Comment: My bad: thought you had LSI 1068; replaced with [LSI 2108](https://www.supermicro.nl/manuals/other/LSI_2108_2208_SAS_MegaRAID_Configuration_Utility.pdf) related information.

Comment: How to find which disk is sda2-8?

Comment: @JasonBrockdorf, I'm running server with System Rescue CD and there is no `ledctl` command. I also can't install any package.

Comment: If the systemrescueCD is read only, then use a more appropriate tool, such as a generic live distribution of something like CentOS. Also install / use MegaCLI. You'll typically have to download this tool from LSI or other RAID card vendors that package the utility on their sites as well.